# Why/how can I stop Excel from changing ' ' to '?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Open Excel 2007 and put

```
' '
```

in a cell and it will show as

```
 '
```

Why? / More importantly / annoyingly  how do you stop it?

I set the format to TEXT. No change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel uses the single quote at the start of a cell to indicate that what follows should be treated as text. If you want to have `' '` display you can enter `'' '`. If you are concerned with having the data `' '` display correctly I don't have a good answer for you without knowing more about your requirements. It is possible that if this applies to a column you could create a custom display format `'@` that would cause it to display as you want.

Comment: It's just annoying to paste in 'Test' and have Test' show up.

Comment: No dice with the format @.

Comment: The custom display format needs to be a single quote followed by the at sign: `'@`, not just the at sign which passes through text.